# Url rewriting, xyz.com/questions has to redirect to somequestions.com/questions, via .htaccess

Tags: php, drupal, url-rewriting

I am PHP developer recently got into Drupal development. But I am novice to URL redirecting etc issues. My issue is, I have a website already like xyz.com running on a  hosting server. Recently I developed another site, which should be displayed as a subdomain like when user types `xyz.com/questions` automatically it has to redirected to `somequestions.com/questions`.

I searched the web and found some results and found that it is URL rewriting but I am unable to set it.

EDIT 1

How to mask the url with the initial URL that I have given. i.e.,  after entering xyz.com/questions it has to redirect the somequestions.com/questions but URL in the address must remain same.

Answer (score 1):

I presume you need [301](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_301) redirection i.e Moved Permanently.

Add following line in your .htaccess file under xyz.com root directory:

```
 Redirect 301 /questions http://184.133.111.012/questions
```